# How to build owncloud in windows?

Tags: qt, cmake, owncloud

I've read the manual of building the client for windows and skipped the steps one by one to step 4.
but unfortunately i'm not familiar with qt and cmake and the manual doesn't explain it as well
can anyone tell me how i should skip the rest of steps?

i don't know how to skip this step :

```
set PATH=C:<OpenSSL Install Dir>\bin;%PATH%
set PATH=C:<qtkeychain Clone Dir>;%PATH%
```

https://doc.owncloud.org/desktop/2.3/building.html#windows-development-build

Answer (score 0):

These commands are to add ahead of your PATH the location of OpenSSL binaries folder and QT Keychain clone folder.

It's suppose you have this two tools already installed on your system and here you are just telling where to find them.

Comment: would you explain more? i'v downloaded the source of both projects and i added the address of them to the system variables but in Qt5 i cant compile the project - Error: Could NOT find Qt5Keychain